# In NodeJS devtools, why are ports being suggested when I click on the Connection panel?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

In NodeJS devtools, why are ports being suggested when I click on the Connection panel?

I am also wondering how can I know which ports to connect to?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `why` - because that's how the GUI (chrome devtools) connect to the node.js built-in debugger. The actual debugger is just a network service (kind of like how gdb is just a terminal application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the port used by node with debugger option. If you don't specify port, I believe default is 9229. You can run node with debug option by `node --inspect app.js`. You can specify port by `node --inspect=9230 app.js`